# How android accept multiple array data?

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, laravel-5

newbie here. I developed my backend with laravel, and it does return me result when i signed in to the system. But when this data pass to android, i am not sure how to handle it.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "a",
        "email": "ddd@gmail.com",
        "address": null,
        "created_at": "2017-09-03 14:51:16",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-03 14:51:16",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test",
                "description": "test",                
                "pivot": {
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "items_id": 1,
                    "status": 1,
                    "created_at": "2017-09-03 14:51:48",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "address": "gdhsjj",
                    "price": "2.0",
                    "updated_at": "2017-09-03 14:51:48"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test",
                "pivot": {
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "items_id": 1,
                    "status": 1,
                    "created_at": "2017-09-03 14:52:02",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "address": "gdhsjj",
                    "price": "1.0",
                    "updated_at": "2017-09-03 14:52:02"
                }
            },
]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "dd",
        "email": "dd@gmail.com",
        "address": "123",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "items": []
    }
]
```

This is some example of my data when i receive from the server. I was able to display the data in android application. Here is the sample when i get the data, and how my server gonna to handle it.

```
 if (status.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
                    JSONArray jsonArrayDetail = json.getJSONArray("detail");
                    ArrayList<PurchasedInfo> purchasedInfos = new ArrayList<PurchasedInfo>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject jsobObjectDetail = jsonArrayDetail.getJSONObject(i);
                        PurchasedInfo purchasedInfo = new PurchasedInfo();
                        purchasedInfo.setI_id(jsobObjectDetail.getString("id"));
                        purchasedInfo.setI_name(jsonObject.getString("name"));


    purchasedInfo.setI_price(jsonObject.getString("price"));
                            purchasedInfo.setI_image(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                            purchasedInfos.add(purchasedInfo);
                        }
}
```

This works fine if the data is pretty straight forward, but if i want to get the data from `items`, i am not sure how to do that. Does everything need to convert first from the server? Or i can straight display the data when i get the data?

ps:My question is a bit messy, hope you guys can understand or help me edit my question. Thanks. If anything unclear, please do let me know.

Comment: do you have data and details in your JSON?

Comment: Yes, I already have the data in json, that I show in above

Comment: in above response there is no data and details display. And the pivot, is't a JSONArray too?

Comment: @G.Dator, yes it it

Comment: use dranreb dinos answer :) in that way of code you can achieve what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have another Class which handles the data for the items and add another `Arraylist<ItemInfoClass> itemInfoClass` on your `PurchasedInfo`. Then try this code to extract items from your `json`:

```
 if (status.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
                JSONArray jsonArrayDetail = json.getJSONArray("detail");
                ArrayList<PurchasedInfo> purchasedInfos = new ArrayList<PurchasedInfo>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject jsobObjectDetail = jsonArrayDetail.getJSONObject(i);
                    PurchasedInfo purchasedInfo = new PurchasedInfo();
                    purchasedInfo.setI_id(jsobObjectDetail.getString("id"));
                    purchasedInfo.setI_name(jsonObject.getString("name"));


                    JSONArray itemArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("items"))
                    for (int j = 0; j < itemArray.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject itemjson = new JSONObject(itemarray.getString(i))
                        ItemInfo itemInfo = new ItemInfo();

                        itemInfo.setID(itemjson.getString("id"));
                        itemInfo.setName(itemjson.getString("name"));
                        itemInfo.setDescription(itemjson.getString("description"));
                        itemInfo.setPivot(itemjson.getString("pivot"));
                        //pivot is still formatted as JSON

                        purchasedInfo.itemInfoClass.add(itemInfo);


                    }


                    purchasedInfo.setI_price(jsonObject.getString("price"));
                    purchasedInfo.setI_image(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                    purchasedInfos.add(purchasedInfo);
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to you if you parse the JSON response with GSON, Jackson or another library like that. Then you can just use a `List` of your models.

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

https://github.com/google/gson

http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-how-to-parse-json-in-android-with-gson/